# Tool to get installed components on a PC

Tags: windows-xp, computer-building, components, hardware-detection

Can anyone suggest some good tools that generate a report of all installed components in a PC? Ideally one that is easy to use.

I need to upgrade my father's computer but won't have access to it until the time comes to do the job. I would like to order the new components beforehand so that I can get it done as quickly as possible. Therefore an easy-to-use tool that generates a report he can email would be perfect.

I vaguely remember there being a small app which would generate an HTML report, but I can't for the life of me remember the name. It's a bit like the system analyser on Crucial.com but it goes into much more detail.

It would need to run on XP.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Rich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy).

> Speccy is an advanced System Information tool for your PC. Need to find out what's inside your computer? No problem! Speccy will give you all the information you need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [PC-Wizard](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/pc-wizard.html) from CPUID or [Fresh Diagnose](http://www.freshdevices.com/freshdiag.html). They are freeware and they can export your system info as a report.

Answer (score 0):

I've occasionally used [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html).