# In Windows 8, how do I find out my motherboard's manufacturer and model?

Tags: windows-8, motherboard, device-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine a computer’s specs?](https://superuser.com/questions/59143/how-can-i-determine-a-computers-specs)
>   [Tool to get installed components on a PC](https://superuser.com/questions/190993/tool-to-get-installed-components-on-a-pc/190995#190995)
>   [A tool for collecting system information?](https://superuser.com/questions/274306/a-tool-for-collecting-system-information/274312#274312)

How can I identify the manufacturer and model of my motherboard without having to physically disassemble computer, and preferably with system tools and not external software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Piriform's Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) is a free system information tool, compatible with Windows XP/7/8.  You can download a portable version to avoid having to install the program, and it can reveal the manufacturer and model of the motherboard, as well as many sub-components (main chipset, southbridge, BIOS info, etc...).

As far as I know, no built-in system tool can identify more than what chipset the motherboard it's based off of (going by what you can find in in Device Manager, `devmgmt.msc`), as there's no one "driver" for the motherboard itself (the computer just sees the individual hardware components).